# Finding XML nodes with jQuery and putting into existing HTML table

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, xml

I'm trying to pull some stock info from an XML feed and write it to some existing divs on my website.

**UPDATE:** I'm now using a php proxy because of [CORS](http://ryankirkman.com/2012/03/30/pass-through-cross-domain-proxy-jquery.html). See code below.

**UPDATE 2:** Ok, getting there. My updated jQuery below is working for the first `stockPrice` variable, but not for the remaining three. The data being pulled for all of them are numbers, so I'm not sure why only one would be working.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="sidenavwrap">

    <div class="sidenavhd"><p class="stocktitle">XXXX (Common Stock)</div>


    <div class="ctcol3"><p class="stocklft">Exchange</p></div>
    <div class="ctcol4"><p class="stocklft">NASDAQ (US Dollar)</p></div>    
    <div id="stock-divider"></div>  

    <div class="ctcol3"><p class="stocklft">Price</p></div>
    <div class="ctcol4"><p class="stocklft" id="stockPrice"></p></div>  
    <div id="stock-divider"></div>

    <div class="ctcol3"><p class="stocklft">Change (%)</p></div>
    <div class="ctcol4"><p class="stockpriceneg" id="changePercent"></p></div>  
    <div id="stock-divider"></div>

    <div class="ctcol3"><p class="stocklft">Volume</p></div>
    <div class="ctcol4"><p class="stocklft" id="stockVolume"></p></div> 
    <div id="stock-divider"></div>

    <p style="text-align: center;">Minimum 10 minute delay</p>


    <div id="stock-divider"></div>  

    <br><br><br>
<!-- end sidenavwrap --></div>
```

This is my proxy.php:

```
// Set return content type
header('Content-type: application/xml');

// Website url to open
$url = 'http://xml.corporate-ir.net/irxmlclient.asp?compid=XXXXXX&reqtype=quotes';

// Get the content
$handle = fopen($url, "r");

// If there is something, read and return
if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
        echo $buffer;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

And this is my jQuery for pulling the data via the proxy:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.get("includes/proxy.php", function (data){

        // Some callback functions
        var stockPrice = ($(data).find('Trade').text());
        var changeValue = ($(data).find('Change').text());
        var stockVolume = ($(data).find('Volume').text());

        var changePercentLong = (changeValue / (stockPrice - changeValue)) * 100;
        var changePercent = changePercentLong.toFixed(2);

        $('#stockPrice').html('$' + stockPrice);
        $('#changePercent').html(changeValue + ' (' + changePercent + '%)');
        $('#stockVolume').html(stockVolume);

        if (changeValue >= 0) {
            $('#changePercent').removeClass('stockpriceneg').addClass('stockprice');
        } else {
            $('#changePercent').removeClass('stockprice').addClass('stockpriceneg');
        }

    });

});
</script>
```

**UPDATE 2:** Still not getting any errors in the console, and now I have the first variable showing correctly, but the others are only showing `0`'s(they should be `-0.23`, some math with the previous variable, and `5039270` respectively):

[image: My front-end result]

I think it's really just a syntax error in my jQuery, but I'm not quite polished enough in my JS/jQuery to spot it. I'm sure someone more experienced could identify the problem in a second. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? Many thanks!

Comment: Try using $.parseXML()

Comment: Sorry, where would that go in my jquery?

Comment: var dataobj = $.parseXML(xml);   Please go through below link https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/                                                                 Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't think that's what I need. I'm pulling in the XML document already. Why would I need to parse it as a string and turn it back into an XML doc?

Comment: Can you create fiddle? I tried creating the same but ajax call is not accessible.

Comment: This is what I have using a test.xml file: https://jsfiddle.net/5m78pkq5/1/

Comment: After a bunch of tweaking it ended up being, as expected, a few pretty minor typos, capitalization errors, etc. Just wish I hadn't wasted a bounty on it :/ Code above has been update to the working version.

Comment: can you please post the console errors you are getting?

Comment: I got it working, but thanks for the reply. See my comment above.

Comment: Can you provide the `compid=XXXXXX` id value or the XML source code that this link fetches?

Comment: Please see my comment above—I got it working already with the revised code above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the jQuery that ended up working with the PHP proxy I posted in the original question:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.get("includes/proxy.php", function (data){

        // Some callback functions
        var stockPrice = ($(data).find('Trade').text());
        var changeValue = ($(data).find('Change').text());
        var stockVolume = ($(data).find('Volume').text());

        var changePercentLong = (changeValue / (stockPrice - changeValue)) * 100;
        var changePercent = changePercentLong.toFixed(2);

        $('#stockPrice').html('$' + stockPrice);
        $('#changePercent').html(changeValue + ' (' + changePercent + '%)');
        $('#stockVolume').html(stockVolume);

        if (changeValue >= 0) {
            $('#changePercent').removeClass('stockpriceneg').addClass('stockprice');
        } else {
            $('#changePercent').removeClass('stockprice').addClass('stockpriceneg');
        }

    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your code with following. Hope it helps.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://xml.corporate-ir.net/irxmlclient.asp?compid=XXXXXX&reqtype=quotes",
        dataType: "xml",
        complete: function (xml) {
            var xmlDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xml.responseText, "application/xml")
            var nodes = xmlDoc.querySelectorAll('IRXML StockQuotes Stock_Quote')[0];
            var stockPrice = parseInt(nodes.querySelectorAll('Trade')[0].textContent);
            var changeValue = parseInt(nodes.querySelectorAll('Change')[0].textContent); // $(this).find('Change').text();
            var changePercent = (changeValue / (stockPrice - changeValue)) * 100;
            var stockVolume = nodes.querySelectorAll('Volume')[0].textContent; //$(this).find('Volume').text();
            $('#stockPrice').html('$' + stockPrice);
            $('#changePercent').html('+' + changeValue + ' (' + changePercent + '%)');
            $('#stockVolume').html(stockVolume);
        },
        error: function (errorData) {
            console.log('Error: request failed!');
            console.log(errorData);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This works with the static `test.xml` file on my server, but not with the url in your example(along with the correct `compid`). Any ideas what could be causing it to fail?

Comment: Actually I downloaded the same file for testing at my side as I also don't have access to that URL.

Comment: Yea, unfortunately I need it to work with that feed.